Movie about a mall Santa set in either Eastern European or Asian Country
This is a movie about the difficulties that a man, who desperately needs work, goes through when he finds a job playing Santa in a Mall during the Christmas season, even though he is Muslim and he lives in a country or region where there is a Muslim majority?  The trailer made allusion to his being mocked by his family, friends and others for playing Santa.
The mall looked like it had expensive stores, maybe there were a lot of tourists or foreigners shopping there and that was why the mall admin wanted a Santa?  
I meant foreign film because usually movies that are not made in the U.S. are in the foreign film category.  I mentioned Eastern European, or Asian country but could be Southeastern European, like Turkey perhaps since Turkey is where St Nicholas is known to have lived, maybe despite being mostly a Muslim country Santa is still a part of their celebrations?
I couldn’t say the language.  It looked like it was subtitled.
Perhaps Turkish?  Also, it might be he was hired at a big store and not by the mall admin but I remember some scene showing him on an escalator.
I believe it is from about 7 years ago, 2008 or 2009?

Hi! Do you remember the year of release? Where\when did you see it?

What language... "Foreign" is kinda broad?

Everywhere is 'foreign' to someone :/

I updated my post to show additional information.

Neseli Hayat (2009)
From: cnn.com

"Neseli Hayat" or "A Cheerful Life" is the story of a down-on-his-luck, working class Turk who is hired to work as a mall Santa.
  The trouble is he doesn't really know who Santa Claus is, and needs some very basic lessons.
  In one scene, a manager drills the main character, Riza and several other hired Santas on how to give Saint Nick's hearty bellow, "ho-ho-ho."
  In another segment, a bearded, costumed Riza enters a waiting room and extends the traditional Muslim greeting "A salam aleyekum" to four other mall Santas, who answer back without looking up "aleyekum salam."


That's it!  Thank you so much!  After reading your answer I also found a great article that mentions this movie.  It's called "Turkey Marks Legend of Father Christmas" and it gives a great explanation of Turkish customs and relationship with the story of Santa.  Here is the link in case anyone is curious:  [link]http://www.newsmax.com/t/newsmax/article/452573.  Unfortunately I cannot find it to view online and the DVD that is sold online cannot be used in the U.S.A.

You're welcome!
Maybe you can watch film at this link: http://www.dizihdfilm1.net/neseli-hayat-full-tek-parca-hd-izle.html
